# How to retrieve an element of ("1", "2", "3") Scala object?

Tags: scala, tuples

I am stuck in an embarrassingly simple issue in Scala (which I am new to).

How to retrieve second (let's say) element (`"2"`) from such a structure in `Scala`:

```
scala> val a = ("1", "2", "3")
a: (String, String, String) = (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with tuples try just this expression: `a._2`

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with tuples you can do either of the following:

```
val res = a._2

val (_, res, _) = a // sets res to "2"

val res = a match { case (_, i, _) => i } // same as above, just longer

// if your tuple appears in a list you can do something like this:
lst.map{ case (_, i, _) => /* do stuff with i */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getClass` to see that the class's name is `scala.Tuple3`.

```
scala> a.getClass.getName
res0: java.lang.String = scala.Tuple3
```

Unfortunately, the documentation for `Tuple3` is hidden in the API, but you can get to it with this direct link.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Tuple3

> A tuple of 3 elements; the canonical representation of a scala.Product3.
>
> `_1` - Element 1 of this `Tuple3`
>
> `_2` - Element 2 of this `Tuple3`
>
> `_3` - Element 3 of this `Tuple3`

Alternatively, you could have used tab completion in the REPL to see the list of public members of `a`.

```
scala> a.
_1                _2                _3
asInstanceOf      canEqual          copy
isInstanceOf      productArity      productElement
productElements   productIterator   productPrefix
toString          zip               zipped
```

So, the answer is: You can access the `_2` field directly.

```
scala> a._2
res1: java.lang.String = 2
```

Although this is generally discouraged in favor of pattern matching.

```
scala> a match { case (x, y, z) => y }
res2: java.lang.String = 2
```